# How to you force fsck at reboot on FreeBSD10?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, fsck

I need to force a file system check on reboot to try and fix my mounted file system.
All the commands/methods I find are obsolete in FreeBSD10

```
[\u@vader:/root] # tune2fs -c 1 /dev/vtbd0p2
tune2fs: not found
[\u@vader:/root] # pkg install tune2fs
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'tune2fs' have been found in the repositories
```

How do you force filesystem check and fix errors at next reboot, just for a one time repair?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to handle this is to reboot the system into single user mode, and do the `fsck` by hand. If, for whatever reason, that's not an option for you, the next best way to handle it is to twiddle a couple of `rc.conf` knobs. Specifically, these:

```
background_fsck="NO"
fsck_y_enable="YES"
fsck_y_flags="-f"
```

Reboot, and the `rc` subsystem should take care of it for you. Note that `rc.early` was [deprecated](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-rc/2007-October/001211.html) in FreeBSD back in 2007.

Comment: Still no fsck at boot   https://bpaste.net/show/f6587fde8a71

Comment: What filesystem are you using on that device?

Comment: this is a '3 month ago installed', default LAMP stack with a pure ports installation of everything FreeBSD10 installation using the default UFS filesystem  https://bpaste.net/show/f5630f232b1d

Comment: What does the `/etc/fstab` entry for `/dev/vtbd0p2` look like? Specifically, is the last field set to anything other than 0?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the

```
background_fsck="NO"
fsck_y_enable="YES"
fsck_y_flags="-f"
```

approach is not working either (different 10.x Versions). So I use this 'dirty' hack for `/etc/rc.d/root`:

```
--- /tmp/root.orig  2018-06-09 00:56:23.089825000 +0200
+++ /etc/rc.d/root  2018-06-09 00:56:03.831574000 +0200
@@ -22,6 +22,9 @@
    [Nn][Oo] | '')
        ;;
    *)
+                # Uncomment the below line to run FORCED fsck on ALL mounts in /etc/fstab during boot:
+                /sbin/fsck -fy || /sbin/fsck -fy
+
        if ! mount -uw /; then
            echo 'Mounting root filesystem rw failed, startup aborted'
            stop_boot true
```

That way, it's working for sure.
**WARNING**: comment again the /sbin/fsck... line after you run this, as this costs time and can be a risk, if a fsck is not the thing you should do.

Answer (score 1):

`tune2fs` is a tool from [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) for handling ext2/3/4 file systems :)

For FreeBSD UFS, [tunefs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tunefs) can be used, but it's not able to set anything `fsck` related. There's a [lengthly discussion](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2009-March/195504.html) about forcing `fsck` after a reboot, the best answer from this thread seems to be ["don't"](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2009-March/195525.html) and rely on `background_fsck="YES"` or [force it](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2009-March/195510.html) via `/etc/rc.early`:

`echo '/sbin/fsck -y -f' >> /etc/rc.early`

Comment: No fsck at boot. I had tried a similar command prior with the same 'no dice' result.

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD has properly working forced unmount, so you don't really need to do this at boot.  Just log in (remotely), remount rootfs as read-only (`mount -fur /`), do fsck manually (`fsck -y /`) and then reboot the machine.